# htaccess rewrite url with and without query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a rewrite rule that works when accessing a direct URL that doesn't have a parameter in it.

Example URL: http://mev-hongkong.com/product-category/babies-tots/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mev-hongkong\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^product-category/babies-tots(/.*)?$ https://mothersenvogue.com.hk/shop/all-babies-tots$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

However, I also have the same URLs that has a parameter that I also need to redirect to the same URL output. I tried manipulating the rewrite rule and added a `%{QUERY_STRING}` condition like the below rule but when I test it with the URL that has the parameter, the query strings are still not being stripped out.

Example url with parameter: http://mev-hongkong.com/product-category/babies-tots/?add_to_wishlist=8836

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mev-hongkong\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^add_to_wishlist=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^product-category/babies-tots(/.*)?$ https://mothersenvogue.com.hk/shop/all-babies-tots$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

What did I miss to correctly strip off the query strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`QSD`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd) flag does exactly this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mev-hongkong\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^product-category/babies-tots(/.*)?$ https://mothersenvogue.com.hk/shop/all-babies-tots$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE,QSD]
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Anonymous! This completely solved it!

Comment: @Weisen Great. Glad I could help.